# How do I easy_install Swampy?

Tags: python, installation, easy-install, swampy

Following the tutorial on python.org I tried to install Swampy in the following ways:

- `easy_install -f http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/install.html`
- `easy_install http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/swampy-2.0.python.zip`
- `easy_install swampy-2.0` (Swampy's folder was already placed in the site-packages folder).

But none of those are working!  what the bobba am I doing wrong?

Comment: If it's already in your site-packages folder, what's the problem?

Comment: There is an error message.  The reason why there is a problem when it is in the site-packages is that I tried to use the command from TurtleWorld import * that also returned an error message.

Comment: Delete it out of your `site-packages` folder, then try your second command again.

Comment: Just tried that and there is an error message saying there is a syntax error.

Comment: Paste the traceback in your question.

Comment: Please post the exact commands and the exact error messages you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You may get this if you are running Python 3.x, and swampy is only compatible with Python 2.x. That would explain syntax errors (assuming the version of swampy on PyPI isn't broken for some other reason).